# Updated time from user in hh mm sec format using telegram bot

Tags: python, timer, python-telegram-bot

I tried to get response time of user replay from the telegram bot API, but it is  not working.  update.message response time suggests the better way to get time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a [`date`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) attribute in the `message` object in Telegram's Bot API. You can use [`update.effective_message.date`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#Message.date) to retrieve it, it is internally turned to a `datetime` object by the `python-telegram-bot` library.

Comment: Thank you  working perfectly result  **2017-09-19 14:05:04** will it returns only second as integer  time object